# Switching boolean from false to true whenever a variable is being changed within a if loop, if changed include form

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic, filter-var

I have my error catching variables set as false so whenever the page loads there isn't any error messages thrown out. I have a variable `$error` that's initially set as just an initializer, e.g. `$error = " ";`. Whenever there is an error, I would like for `$error` to be set to the message each error is echoing and if `$error` doesn't equal what it was originally initialized with then it should include my form page to allow the user to try again.

What I've tried  is to set the `$error` variable to a new string for the specified error, e.g. "You can't leave the price box empty!" and at the end of my initial if loop, there's another if loop checking whether or not  `$error` was changed and if it was then include the form page again. As of now, my variables never change and only stay what they were initially set as.

```
$pError = false;
$cError = false;
$error = " ";

if(!isset($_GET['pPrice']) || (!isset($_GET['cPrice']))){ //if not set include form
    include "form.php";
}
if(isset($_GET['pPrice']) && isset($_GET['cPrice'])){ //if set get variables from form
    $pPrice = $_GET['pPrice'];
    $cPrice = $_GET['cPrice'];
    $validateP = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pPrice', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT); //checks to see if value is a float
    $validateC = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'cPrice', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT); //checks to see if value is a float

    if(empty($_GET['pPrice']) && (empty($_GET['cPrice']))){ //both fields empty
        $error = "<h2 class='error'>Please make sure you fill out all the fields!</h2>";
    }
    else if(empty($_GET['pPrice'])){ //first field empty
        $error = "<h2 class='error'>Previous price can't be empty!</h2>";
    }
    else if(empty($_GET['cPrice'])){ //second field empty
        $error = "<h2 class='error'>Current price can't be empty!</h2>";
    }
    else if(!$validateP && !$validateC){ //both fields have incorrect inputs
        $error = "<h2 class='error'>Please enter numbers only!</h2>";
    }
    else if(!$validateP){ //first field has a incorrect input
        $error = "<h2 class='error'>Previous Price must be a valid number!</h2>";
    }
    else if(!$validateC){ //second field has a incorrect input
        $error = "<h2 class='error'>Current Price must be a valid number!</h2>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Your results have been submitted!";                 
    }

    if (!$error == " ") {
        $pError == true;
        $cError == true;
        echo $error;
        include "form.php";
    } else{
        $pError = false;
        $cError = false;
    }
}
```

Expected results are if user enters a incorrect value or doesn't enter a value at all, update the variable $error for that specific error, change the boolean from false to true, then allow for another try. If no errors, echo the "success" message.

Comment: Why not use an array for the errors, and then simply `count` it.  Then your users can see all the errors.  There isn't too much that I hate more then filling in a big form getting shown 1 error at a time, and wasting 15 minutes re-submitting the page.

Comment: are you implying put all the error messages in an array and call the specified index for the error message?

Comment: No I am implying you put all the errors in an array and then show them all to the user.  you can even use the field name as the key of that array and then show them where they belong.  Just saying...

Comment: so basically a push for each error? the reason I'm doing it this way is because in my css I'm wanting to change the background color of the specific box(es) that have errors. That's the reasoning behind using the booleans for a if-else statement within my form's css.

Comment: Seems it would be easier to highlight fields with errors if you had an array of errors keyed by the field name? Empty array means no errors.

Comment: @GregSchmidt - exactly.

Comment: As you dont use `$pError` or `$cError` their existance appears to be unnecessary

Comment: What does your `form.php` look like? Is your main problem perhaps that it's `POST`ing data but you're checking the `$_GET`?

Comment: my form.php is a method="get"

Comment: Also if one of you could link me to a page for more information on this errors in array concept, I'd greatly appreciate it. Although I would very like to complete it this way, I will look into doing the array style